# Objective-C: updating UITableView with recursive function?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to re-call core-data in UITable using model view. I am  in UITable  in  - (void)viewDidLoad  method using  getting some data from internet and setting them entities and showing them on UITable.It works normal ,but Now I am trying to use new addModel view and in this model view I can type user name in textfield and save it in person entity.But when model view disappears my table not updates,after re-lunching it updates but because of not running vievDidLoad again it doesn`t gets value form internet.

i thought that am I have to use some recursive function? But where must I put it?in UITable which function calls every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html/), the iPhone equivalent of NSArrayController, is probably what you need. As the docs say NSFetchedResultsController

> optionally monitors changes to objects
>   in its associated managed object
>   context, and reports changes in the
>   results set to its delegate (see “The
>   Controller’s Delegate”).

so it should respond when you update an entity.